# unable to install graphlab after typing graphlab.get_dependencies() function

Tags: python, anaconda, graphlab

The code shows following errors:

[image]

ACTION REQUIRED: Dependencies libstdc++-6.dll and libgcc_s_seh-1.dll not found.

1. Ensure user account has write permission to C:\Users\dungeon_master\Anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\graphlab
2. Run graphlab.get_dependencies() to download and install them.
3. Restart Python and import graphlab again.

By running the above function, you agree to the following licenses.

when i try to write `get_dependencies()` afterwards it shows the errors shown in image

```
ContentTooShortError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-9e64085fb919> in <module>()
----> 1 graphlab.get_dependencies()

C:\Users\dungeon_master\Anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\graphlab\dependencies.pyc in get_dependencies()
     39 
     40     print('Downloading gcc-libs.')
---> 41     (dllarchive_file, dllheaders) = urllib.urlretrieve('http://repo.msys2.org/mingw/x86_64/mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc-libs-5.1.0-1-any.pkg.tar.xz')
     42     dllarchive_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
     43 

C:\Users\dungeon_master\Anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\urllib.pyc in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data, context)
     96     else:
     97         opener = _urlopener
---> 98     return opener.retrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
     99 def urlcleanup():
    100     if _urlopener:

C:\Users\dungeon_master\Anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\urllib.pyc in retrieve(self, url, filename, reporthook, data)
    287         if size >= 0 and read < size:
    288             raise ContentTooShortError("retrieval incomplete: got only %i out "
--> 289                                        "of %i bytes" % (read, size), result)
    290 
    291         return result

ContentTooShortError: retrieval incomplete: got only 105704 out of 546800 bytes
```

Comment: In order for you question to get answered, and for the answer to be useful to others too, you need to **copy the code into your question** as text, not as an image.

Answer (score 1):

- Well, I faced the same questions 1 hour ago, and I fixed it now.
- For the 2 .dll files, you can search the internet to download them, copy them to you directory:C:\Users\dungeon_master\Anaconda3\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\graphlab.
- In ipython notebook, run import graphlab, and then run graphlab.get_dependencies(). Wait 1 minute, the base package will download.
- After the 2 steps, you may restart you computer, then you will find everything back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

The error exists for me as well after the following the above steps. What i realised is that the these two dependencies needs to be extracted in the "cython" folder inside "graphlab" folder. So i copied the same folder from a different installation that was working for me previously and volla.. "import graphlab" was successful. In case anyone needs it, below is the link to the zip of my "cython" folder. Just replace this "cython" folder inside graphlab (Usual location is '/Anaconda2/envs/gl-env/Lib/site-packages/graphlab'. I hope it helps someone

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1voSQs3jo7Jc2l6RTBzWGhYUUU